# Alternative to MapTiler for tiling a GeoTIFF

Tags: c#, geotiff-tiff, gdal2tiles

I'm currently using MapTiler Pro console version, called from C# code as process with the following parameters:

> -geodetic -nodata 0 0 0 -f png32 -o result/ -tms -resampling bilinear -srs "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs" -zoom 8 12 source.tif

Is there any alternatives to MapTiler for using from code? I tried vips's dzsave, but output differs from needed and it lacks some functions, like tiling exact levels.

I also use gdal's c# bindings, but it lacks gdal2tiles methods, which, from what I've found, is the only alternative.

Comment: Gdal2tiles is Python script. Perhaps you can call it from C# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11779143/how-do-i-run-a-python-script-from-c.

Comment: Using python scripts means installing python on target PC, which is not an option in my case. I'm looking for portable solution if possible.

Comment: If you can spend some time you may be able to rewrite gdal2tiles.py with C#.

Comment: Or freeze it into an executable using e.g. pyinstaller

Comment: @gberard thanks, that's a good idea, I'm gonna give it a try.

Answer (score 2):

So I ended up rewriting gdal2tiles.py. Freezing it into executable wasn't very successful, it somehow lacks multithreading bindings. [Here's](https://github.com/Gigas002/GTiff2Tiles) my repository of Gdal2Tiles on C#, feel free to use it, but be aware, that in current state it's working only like gdal2tiles.py with the following command line args:

```
input.tif outputDirectory -s EPSG:4326 -p geodetic -r cubicspline --tmscompatible -z 10-14
```

I plan on developing it further later, so stay tuned!

Comment: I have a question regarding your development. I have nowhere else to contact you. Please see https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/360634/gtiff2tiles-how-to-generate-tiles-without-processing-tons-of-blank-tiles - thank you.