# Gtiff2Tiles - How to generate tiles without processing tons of blank tiles

Tags: gdal

I am using GTiff2Tiles to create tiles from my TIF. (I am testing on level 11).

However, I am unable to complete the test because it is generating loads of blank tiles, so many that after 20 minutes it is still generating them. See the image below.

My command I am using is :

```
gtiff2tiles -i "input.tif" -o "C:\outputdir" -t "C:\tempdir" --minz 8 --maxz 11 --a join --tms true --threads 4
```

What can I do get rid of all the blank tiles so it generates faster? I am not an expert with this, and I am trying to migrate from gdal2tiles as GTiff2Tiles. Here is what the tiles look like in the output directory - tens of thousands of them.

[image]

I have used the gdal tag as Gtiff2Tiles is new and does not have a tag yet, but it is essentially a clone of gdal2tiles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry it took a while to conatact you back. Since I'm visiting stackoverflow pretty rarely, I'm answering questiong about GTiff2Tiles in the [repository](https://github.com/Gigas002/GTiff2Tiles). So feel free to open a new [issue](https://github.com/Gigas002/GTiff2Tiles/issues) if anything goes wrong.

Regarding your current problem, try out the latest preview build, [here's](https://github.com/Gigas002/GTiff2Tiles/releases/tag/v2.0.0-ci303) this release page. I've tested this build with my data and it seems to work fine for now.

The arguments for console application have changed a bit, algorithm parameter have gone away completely, so your starting string would like more like:

`gtiff2tiles.console -i "input.tif" -o "C:\outputdir" -t "C:\tempdir" --minz 8 --maxz 11 --tms true --threads 4`

If it still won't help much, I'll need to some more data from you to locate a problem.